# How do I set the FPS when using ffmpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg, avconv

I'm trying to save my CCTV stream into segments of 300 seconds with a FPS of 7. Here's my command:

`ffmpeg -r 7 -i rtsp://192.168.1.100/...stream=0.sdp -acodec aac -strict -2 -vcodec copy -f segment -segment_time 300 -segment_format mp4 "mon1-%03d.mp4"`

The output file doesn't seem to respect the '-r 7' command (for FPS = 7). Does anyone know how to set the FPS of the output?

Comment: Below answer was correct regarding option after -i but you'd need to re-encode video. Otherwise maybe look here - https://superuser.com/questions/1088382/change-framerate-in-ffmpeg-without-reencoding

Answer (score 0):

probably your problem is the version of ffmpeg.

I was having the same error with the following command:

```
$ ffmpeg -i 'inputstream' -r 'Nframerate' -vcodec copy -acodec copy -t 'Xseconds' -y 'outputfile.avi'
```

The output file always has 30 fps but only in my raspberry pi 3, not in my PC, this is the version that is working for me in my PC from the repos of Ubuntu 17.04:

```
$ ffmpeg --help

    ffmpeg version 3.2.4-1build2 Copyright (c) 2000-2017 the ffmpeg developers
    built with gcc 6.3.0 (Ubuntu 6.3.0-8ubuntu1) 20170221....
```

In the raspberry pi 3 there is no ffmpeg but avconv in the repos:

```
$ avconv --help
    avconv version 11.9-6:11.9-1~deb8u1+rpi1, Copyright (c) 2000-2017 the Libav developers
    built on Apr 26 2017 06:57:28 with gcc 4.9.2 (Raspbian 4.9.2-10)...
```

so I manually compile and install ffmpeg in my raspberry:

So: download the latest from https://www.ffmpeg.org/download.html

```
$ ./configure
$ make -j4 #in rpi3 there are 4 threads
$ sudo make install
```

Now the version of ffmpeg is a new one: i.e.

```
$ ffmpeg --help
    ffmpeg version 3.3.2 Copyright (c) 2000-2017 the FFmpeg developers
    built with gcc 4.9.2 (Raspbian 4.9.2-10)...
```

and does not presents the bug with the framerate.

Comment: `-r` output option is ignored when using stream copy mode (`-vcodec copy`/`-c:v copy`/`-c copy`).

Comment: I check using ($man ffmpeg) and  (#ffmpeg --help) and there is not such reference. my camera was configured for 5 FPS and the output video properties shows 30FPS and a larger video size unless I manually use the (-r 5) option.